# Preventing touch event on Secondary Screen in Multi-Display device

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a POS multi-display device. It has two screens. The problem I am facing currently is that I want device to do **nothing** when **Second Screen** is touched. I just want that screen to **display a form** and not receiving any events from it. I have display **extended** in the device .

How can I change the **touch event** to do **nothing** ? If I am on wrong direction,please suggest me.

Comment: Please share code/error you are facing. Try removing event handler for that screen/form.

Comment: @GaurangDave Sir I didn't find touch event handler. So, I have no suitable bit of code to detect that event